# Laravel model properties

Tags: laravel-5

I'm not sure how to best ask the question.  I'm trying to write DRY code and I've got a `Job` model.  A job can have types (ex: full-time, part-time, etc).  If I want to only define the types once where would I put them that I could use them everywhere?  Is the best way to do this something like:

```
class Job extends Model
{
    private static $jobTypes = [
        'full-time',
        'part-time',
    ];

    public static function jobTypes()
    {
        return self::$jobTypes;
    }
}
```

Or does doing a completely separate class make more sense / increase flexibility?

```
class JobTypes
{
    private static $jobTypes = [
        'full-time',
        'part-time',
    ];

    public static function jobTypes()
    {
        return self::$jobTypes;
    }
}
```

Or something else...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the requirement, your first response would be the best practice:

```
class Job extends Model
{
    private static $jobTypes = [
        'full-time',
        'part-time',
    ];

    public static function jobTypes()
    {
        return self::$jobTypes;
    }
}
```

However, sometimes it's beneficial to have all of these variables defined at one place so that you can modify them easily. So if you have more static options like this for various models or for whatever reason, I would suggest to go with config file and define them in: `config->app.php`

and then you can access them from anywhere like so:

`config('app.jobTypes')`

*Makes sense?*